# Replacing Apache Flex with HTML5

Tags: apache-flex

I am writing an application which requires access to the microphone of a device to determine instantaneous volume levels. The app will have a web version, iOS version, and Android version, and must be compatible with as many devices as possible, since the particular user base our application targets may not be able to switch browsers easily.

At first, I looked into using HTML5 for my application. However, it does not seem to be viable for my purposes, because I can't find any cross-platform way to get instantaneous microphone input and many users may be using an out-of-date version of their browser, which would not support HTML5. **Is there any tool which alleviates these challenges and would allow me to use HTML5?**

As a replacement, I began looking into Apache Flex. It seems to have all of the features I seek: It is cross-platform, allows me to access microphone volume levels, and will work even on very old devices, as long as they have Flash installed. However, *many* people predict the imminent death of Flex and strongly argue against using it, opting rather for HTML5. **For my purposes, is Flex an appropriate tool, or would it still not be recommended?**

Comment: Really you don't mean Flex; which is primarily an ActionScript UI Framework. You mean the Adobe Flash Runtimes--Flash Player and Adobe AIR.  It is these runtimes which support microphone access. Although you can definitely use such classes from inside a Flex Application.  I'd go with Flex/The Flash Platform personally. Microphone access is one thing that The Flash Platform does clearly better than individual browsers.  OF course, your app won't run in a mobile browser then; but you can create Native iOS and Android apps.

Comment: As you pointed out yourself: it seems to be the only tool that meets your requirements. So unless you find another one it looks like you don't have a choice.

Comment: Alright. I was hoping there would be a too which does this.

Comment: Ahh, the broken promises of HTML5. :) One year later, still waiting for the "death" of Apache Flex. Hell, Adobe ColdFusion has been "dying" for what now, like 10 years? As for Flash, on mobile that's a dead end path, true. But Flex uses Adobe AIR for mobile deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using PhoneGap or similar backend app which can host a webview and allow you to access native api through JavaScript or JSObject.

For front end, you can use HTML and keep your UI standard across all devices/platforms.

PhoneGap is little bulky but on Android and iOS, you can create a minimal app by hosting WebView and customize it to create JavaScript bridge and write your own native api.

Comment: "keep your UI standard across all devices/platforms" - Yeah, sure... (doubtful without much pain)